# RabbitMq, add value that is not exist from a queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm using rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend() for sending my object to queue. the problem is, I need that queue to store unique data. is there any mechanism to check whether such data is exist in a queue, before putting it to said queue?

Answer (score 0):

No; there is no such mechanism.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26917481)

Comment: Huh? The question is `is there any mechanism ...?`; the answer is simply `No` - nothing to clarify either in the question or answer. It's a completely valid answer IMO.